# "instead of" Vs. "instead to"

Tags: prepositions

Is the usage of "instead to" instead of "instead of" is correct?

For example:

> I ran to the university **instead to** the park.

instead of:

> I ran to the university **instead of** the park.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

> I ran to the university instead to the park.

is just wrong.  You could write

> I ran to the university instead of the park.

or

> I ran to the university instead of *to* the park.

or

> I ran to the university instead of *running to* the park.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you'd see **instead to** is in a context like this:

> We were thinking of taking a day trip to the beach, but went instead to the zoo.

We went to the zoo.

> I didn't run to the park but instead to the university.

I ran to the university.

The abandoned thing (the beach, the university) is not mentioned after **instead** but it could be:

> We were thinking of taking a day trip to the beach, but went instead [of the beach]  to the zoo.
>
> I didn't run to the park but [ran] instead [of the park] to the university.

Comment: So you agree that saying "I ran to the university instead to the park." is wrong. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I do agree that that is wrong.